Does the radial wavefunction of the Hydrogen Atom have a relativistic correction?
Fairly simple question but I have not found a definite answer for. With the Schrodinger equation solution for the Hydrogen atom there are higher-order energy corrections which need to be tacked on to correct for relativistic and other effects. Does the radial wavefunction part of the solution also have higher-order corrections which need to be added?
I am asking because I am wondering if spherical harmonics alone are sufficient to predict electron position behavior compared to experiment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#Solution_to_Dirac_equation

@JeanbaptisteRoux If I am not mistaken, this is essentially the original Schrodinger equation position wavefunction (in terms of spherical harmonic functions) with the incorporation of extra spin variables and accounts for all discrepancies except Lamb Shift and hyperfine?

No, the Dirac equation is fully relativistic. The Lamb Shift and Hyperfine Structure come from Quantum Electrodynamics, which means you consider the quantum electromagnetic field instead of a Coulomb potential.

@JeanbaptisteRoux Yes, the Dirac equation uses spherical harmonics but within a bi-spinor to account for Minkowski space. Is there a complete QED model of the Hydrogen atom, which includes spherical harmonics, and completely agrees with experimental results?

Yes, in theory, but in practice, not in the form you are asking for (as far as I know, and I would be glad to see someone prove me wrong on this point). You can approximate the "true" potential of the proton by the Uehling potential, but it is hard to analytically do the calculation. Of course with simulations everything is simpler...

H atom is one of the precision tests of QED, and you can expect new papers to come out every year using more and more sophisticated theoretical computations v.s. more and more precise experimental measurements. But the radial wavefunction is already different at the basic Dirac level, because the nodes of Schrödinger radial wavefunction will no longer be points of zero electron density.

@naturallyInconsistent So the places that would be zero probability in Schrodinger's will be non-zero probability in Dirac's? Are there visual representations and comparisons of the radial component between Dirac's and experiment?
